# Click Events with Leaflet and GeoJSON

Tags: leaflet, geojson

How do I attach a click event to a GeoJSON that then executes an Ajax function when clicked. I looked into `onEachFeature` but that executes when the GeoJSON is loaded, not when clicked, thus executing a ton of ajax calls!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You were on the right way with `onEachFeature`.

It's just you have to bind event click on each element.

See below (tested)

```
function whenClicked(e) {
  // e = event
  console.log(e);
  // You can make your ajax call declaration here
  //$.ajax(... 
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    //bind click
    layer.on({
        click: whenClicked
    });
}

geojson = L.geoJson(your_data, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Is there a way to have a global click handler, the same for all features without looping?

Comment: Not aware of it. In the official tutorial, always using this way e.g https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/ and https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/ I suppose you wanted one listener like on an `<ul>` tag to know  about its `<li>` child(s) ?!

Comment: Yep, in React I've ended up adding an `onclick` callback on the GeoJSON, so that clicking on any feature triggers a callback. But for styles for example it doesn't seem to exist, you can't have the same color for all feature without applying a function to each feature (and maybe that makes sense technically, I just don't know)

Answer (score 12):

You can do it with slightly less code than ThomasG77's version:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    //bind click
    layer.on('click', function (e) {
      // e = event
      console.log(e);
      // You can make your ajax call declaration here
      //$.ajax(... 
    });

}

geojson = L.geoJson(your_data, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 6):

Just another way as an inline function:

```
geojson = L.geoJson(your_data, {
  style: style,
  onEachFeature: function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

    layer.on('mouseover', function (event) {
      console.log(event);
      // You can make your Ajax call declaration here
      //$.ajax(... 
    });

  }).addTo(map);
```

Comment: can you beautify your code please?